# GEO IP can't run in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, geoip

I'm facing a problem, if-else not working. Here is code.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //ip is - 182.48.65.4
$adsmanager = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ip/country");
         //adsmanager result: BD
if($adsmanager == "BD"){
     echo '1. This is Bangladesh';
} else {
     echo '2. This is USA';
}
```

But After run Output is "2. This is USA"

again when is change

```
 if($adsmanager == "US"){
         echo '1. This is Bangladesh';
    } else {
         echo '2. This is USA';
    }
```

And Output is "2. This is USA"

What is the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: The $adsmanager returns `BD ` extra space.if you print out the length of $adsmanager it will output 3.Thats why compare with `BD` does not work. Look at @riad answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim()` function ...then your match will work. Because the page returns a linebreak with output.

```
if(trim($adsmanager) == "BD"){
     echo '1. This is Bangladesh';
} else {
     echo '2. This is USA';
}
```